# Manually Simulating Onclick or Click Event

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of check-boxes which have `click` event listeners.
Now I have a button that checks all those check-boxes at once.
The problem is that this button does not trigger the click event listener on the check-boxes.

Is there any way to manually call the `click` event on an element?

Comment: And where is the code??

Comment: just trigger onchange event for all targeted checkboxes. Now post any relevant code you are talikng about... BTW, why onclick event on checkbox, looks like you should use instead onchange event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
   var item = $(this);
   if(item.not(":checked")) {
       item.trigger("click");
   }
});
```

Comment: i don't see how this answer question. But question lacks many useful infos and should be closed

Comment: It shows how to trigger `click` event. Which is what was asked.

Comment: But here you are triggering click event on all checkboxes unregarding when "button that checks all those check boxes" is clicked. That's was my point. As this answer has been accepted, we could argue this was the issue OR OP didn't know what he was asking

Comment: Just skipped the `$("#checkAll").click` part, as, judging from question, OP already got that covered.

Comment: Ya, i was just thinking about that, my bad +1

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").change(function () {

            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                alert("something");

            }
        });
    });
    function checkall() {
        $("input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            $(this).prop('checked', true);
            $(this).trigger("change");
        });
    }
</script>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <input type="button" onclick="checkall()" />
</body>
```